# How to add bottom legend title to top when using shape and color

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
mtcars$carb_string <- as.character(mtcars$carb)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = carb_string, shape = carb_string)) +
  geom_point() + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
p <- p +theme(legend.box.background=element_rect(),legend.box.margin=margin(5,5,5,5))
```

gives:

[image]

How do I put the legend title on top center? I've tried quite a few solutions to similar questions but have not quite found anything that works

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, here is one potential solution:

```r
library(ggplot2)
mtcars$carb_string <- as.character(mtcars$carb)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = carb_string, shape = carb_string)) +
  geom_point() + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
p <- p +theme(legend.box.background=element_rect(),legend.box.margin=margin(5,5,5,5))

p +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title.hjust = 0.5,
                              title.position = "top"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>